# Error with user already exists or not in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am facing problem in user checking from my database. I have checked the previous suggestions but that has not helped me...

My code is:

```
<?php include 'conn.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
    $user=$_POST['uname'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $depart=$_POST['department'];
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $pass=$_POST['pass'];
    $cpass=$_POST['cpass'];
    $address=$_POST['address'];
    $securepassword=hash('sha512', $cpass);
    $chk_email="select count(*) from signup where Email='" . $email ."'";
    $chk_user="select count(*) from signup where Username='" . $user . "'";
    $result_mail=mysql_query($chk_email);
    $result_user=mysql_query($chk_user);
    $query_mail=mysql_fetch_row($result_mail);
    $query_user=mysql_fetch_row($result_user);
    if($cpass!==$pass)
    {
        header("location:setting.php");
        echo $_SESSION['pass']="password not match";
        return false;
    }

    if($query_mail[0]>0)
    {
        header("locatio:setting.php");
        echo $_SESSION['username']="Username Already Exist";
        return false;
    }
    if($query_user[0]>0)
    {
        header("location:setting.php");
        echo $_SESSION['email']="Email Already Exists";
        return false;
    }

else
{
    $qry="INSERT INTO signup (First_Name,Last_Name,Username,Email,Department,Employe_Id,Phone,Password,Address) VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$user','$email','$depart','$id','$phone','$securepassword','$address')";

    if(mysql_query($qry))
    {
        echo "<script>window.open('success.php','_self')</script>";
        header('location:index.php');
    }
}
}
?>
```

Can anyone tell me what is the error in my code?

The previous questions and answers have not helped me. I know it is simple as a question but an error is an error.

Comment: What is the error message? Also remember to sanitise the post data to prevent sql injection

Comment: the error is that the if statement cant,t be called/checked, and the else statement will be executed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always insert empty values.

If `$_POST['submit']` is set, you perform checks and assignments.
If not, you insert data into DB. 
Because in else block you don't set value of variables `$fname, $lname ...` you perform insert without data.

Remove `}else{` and it should be fine